# how to compress / minify javascript that has embedded php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, minify, compression

My jquery scripts have some php in them to initiate variables, etc. I'm trying to use something like minify to compress it and deter prying eyes. The php is causing issues. Anybody done anything similar?

here is just an example of my php-infused javascript:

```
    $('input[name=type]:radio').filter('[value=<?=$type?>]').attr('checked', true);
    $('input[name=cert]:checkbox').filter('[value=<?=$cert?>]').attr('checked', true);
    $('input[name=gauge]:checkbox').filter('[value=<?=$gauge?>]').attr('checked', true);
```

Comment: PHP short tags is really enabled?

Comment: The best approch is to separate php and javascript , you can make an ajax call to get a json of your data , then you can access the response and fetch it

Comment: Is the PHP code only in JavaScript strings or is it used anywhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP attempts to completely separate the JavaScript in this way. In your PHP file you keep the values as follows:

file.php:

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
...
<input type="hidden" id ="value_type" value="<?=$type?>" />
<input type="hidden" id ="value_cert" value="<?=$cert?>" />
<input type="hidden" id ="value_gauge" value="<?=$gauge?>" />
...
</body>
</html>
```

file.js:

```
$(function() {

  $.data_values = {

     "type": $("#value_type").val(),
     "cert": $("#value_cert").val(),
     "gauge": $("#value_gauge").val()

  };

});
```

when you have to use the values:

```
$('input[name=type]:radio').filter('[value="'+$.data_values.type +'"]').attr('checked', true);
$('input[name=cert]:checkbox').filter('[value="'+$.data_values.cert +'"]').attr('checked', true);
$('input[name=gauge]:checkbox').filter('[value="'+$.data_values.gauge +'"]').attr('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Minify won't work with PHP. If you have to keep the PHP in there are there isn't too much of it, you could replace it with a known tag (i.e. 'ABCDE', '12345'), then minify it, then substitute the tags with your PHP again.

Comment: That's what I was thinking as well. There isn't much php, so I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

When all of your PHP is in JavaScript strings like in your example code then any minification tool worth its salt should work just fine. If you want to use UglifyJS for example, then you can [try it online](http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/uglifyjs) and see if it works for your code.